UIKIT: Decrease Height of Push Notification programmatically
I have NotificationViewController which was created when I implemented Notification Content Extension and then I got rid of the storyboard so I could programmatically make the view. However I'm having trouble actually reducing the height of the actual push notification when the user does a long press. I thought the view represented the notification itself but it doesn't? I was able to change the height of the notification on storyboard but I'm have a hard time doing it programatically. Any help would be great!
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

/// A View Controller that is activated when a push notification is pressed for a while.
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {
    /// The label that displays the title of the push notification
    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.isHidden = false
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        return label
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100 * 5),
        ])
    }

    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        let content = notification.request.content
        self.titeLabel.text = content.body
    }

}


Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656286/833395
